Is there any way to use dash in variable name in js?
I am currently importing all things from a file using "*" for example -
import * as globalCode from './file_path;
The problem is, I want to import it like
import * as global-code from './file_path;
Is there any possible way to do it in JavaScript?
I have tried to find the solution but as JavaScript allows only alphabets, numbers and underscore in the variable name, so I was unable to find the solution.

No, it is not possible to use a dash in a variable name, because the interpreter will think you want to perform a subtraction.
